# How to load url without protocol to webview?

Tags: android, webview

For example any link without `http//` or `www.` how to load url to the webview. In browser this links works

its my code

`WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
            settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            new MyWebViewClient().shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView, url);`

my link starts from vm(numbers).had.su

Answer (score 0):

You can load as:

URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com");

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("GET");